# Migrate C++ SDK for .Net cross-platform development

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Recently I need to cross-platform develop (Windows and Linux arm64, I am about to develop it by Avalonia) code reader by HIKRobot code reader.

Now the first problem is the windows SDK HIKRobot provide is compiled by .Net Framework 2.0 that .Net 7 cannot use it.

The second problem is the Linux SDK it provided is just like this:
[image]

It seems dotnet cannot reference it also.

I have contacted HIKRobot about this, but HIKRobot refused to provide an SDK for .Net7

Fortunately, it has a C++ DEMO and JAVA SDK (BTW, the JAVA SDK only contains a jar file). It seems C++ code can run cross-platform also.
[image]

I know little about C++, but I have an idea whether this C++ demo can be wrapped into an SDK suitable for .Net 7 cross-platform development.

I read the articles on the Internet, it seems that this can be achieved (via CLR, etc.)

Could you please tell me how to solve the problem I am encountering now? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are in a bit of a mess. I would presume that something named HIKRobot does something with robots, and that this likely involves the operating system in one way or another. This likely requires platform dependent code, and you could use [RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.isosplatform?view=net-7.0) to check the platform and use different libraries depending on the platform.

If the native API a standard C style API you should be able to use [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cross-platform). This should work with either .so or .dll files on their respective platforms. But it would naturally require that you can get a native windows SDK, equivalent to your linux SDK. Note that using this will likely require a bit of experience with native development, since the code style and practices in C# and C is significantly different, and the result of errors is often just "Segmentation fault" or similar.

On windows you could use C++/CLI to wrap native libraries, but as far as I know this is not possible on linux. Since c++/cli does not seem to be prioritized I would not expect this to developed any time soon. So P/Invoke is probably the only way to go on linux.

On windows you could also try to just load the existing .net framework libraries and ignore any warnings about incompatibilities.  There is a significant risk that this would just fail, especially considering the libraries age. But it might be worth a try. At least some .net framework libraries can successfully be loaded in .Net 7.

Comment: I tested the Windows SDK reference by Avalonia and Winform(both by .Net7). Visual Studio reports both with the error:"The reference is invalid or unsupported."

Comment: @MelonNG you would not add native dlls as references to a project. You would just make sure the files is in the same folder as your .exe, or in the search paths of the system, and use the DllImport attribute to do runtime loading. So you should not get any errors until runtime.

Comment: After testing this after my holiday. It works now. Thank you so much.